# XHTML: Placing DIVs in A tags

Tags: html, xhtml, anchor

Is it `alright` to place div tags inside anchor tags?
Will contents of the div redirect the page to the href of the anchor tag?

Comment: Your XHTML will not validate if you place a block-level element inside an inline-level element.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Is it alright to place div tags inside anchor tags?

Yes, if:

1. You are using HTML5/XHTML5; and
2. The anchor tag is not in an inline context. i.e. a descendant of an element that only allows phrasing content.

Otherwise no.

In HTML5/XHTML5 the `<a>` element in not simply an inline element as it is in HTML4/XHTML1. Instead it has a transparent content model, which means that the validation rules for its content are the same as if it wasn't there.

So for example

```
<div>
   <div>Hello World</div>
</div>
```

is valid, so

```
<div>
   <a href="#">
      <div>Hello World</div>
   </a>
</div>
```

is too.

But

```
<p>
   <div>Hello World</div>
</p>
```

is not valid, so

```
<p>
   <a href="#">
      <div>Hello World</div>
   </a>
</p>
```

isn't either.

Comment: Thank you for the extra clarifications.

Answer (score 1):

No that is certainly invalid HTML.

*-Will contents of the div redirect the page to the href of the anchor tag?*
I'm not so sure on what you mean on this one.
But its not the contents of a div that an anchor follows but the anchor's href attribute.

Comment: Ok, thank you. No block-level elements inside elements, got it.

Comment: @Francisc - More specifically, No block level elements inside inline elements. The following are some examples of inline elements: a, strong, span

Answer (score 1):

If what you're trying to achieve is a block-level link, you can simply use CSS:

```
a.block {
    display: block;
    /* everything else */
}

<a class="block">...</a>
```