# CSS problem: Large letter is messing with my div alignments

Tags: css

http://ttt-ai.heroku.com/ is the URL of teh problem (just click yes or no) then click any of the squares, and you'll see what is going on.

a screen shot: [image]

It's just the squares that are getting messed up right now. I haven't put to much thought into how I want to style the X's and O's

Comment: I can't even get past the "yes/no" menu. ...Because only the actual text was clickable.

Comment: @sdleihssirhc: Click it more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get things displaying correctly, try:

```
.ttt_square {
    ...
    float: left;
    ...
}
```

**For one you have a `div` inside an `a`** (Which, as has been pointed out to me in the comments isn't an issue here as you've used the HTML5 doctype):

```
<div id="1x1" class="square_container">
    <a data-remote="true" href="/board/take_turn?id=70&amp;x=1&amp;y=1">
        <div class="ttt_square"> 
            &nbsp;
        </div>
    </a> 
</div>
```

That's now allowed (in HTML4, in yours it's fine)...

About.com's "[valid context](http://webdesign.about.com/od/htmltags/p/bltags_a.htm)" lists are helpful here:

**`<a>` Contents**:

> CDATA Any text that you want linked.
>   The following tags are valid within
>   the  tag: acronym, applet, b,
>   basefont, bdo, big, br, button, cite,
>   code, dfn, em, font, i, iframe, img,
>   input, kbd, label, map, object, q, s,
>   samp, script, select, small, span,
>   strike, strong, sub, textarea, tt, u,
>   var

Note the lack of `div` in this list.

Comment: Thank you. =D I changed my divs inside the a's to span's. thanks!

Comment: No problem, glad it was helpful! Doing that will ensure your game performs more predictably across a much wider set of browsers :)

Comment: "For one you have a `div` inside an `a`: [...] That's not allowed...". You're not quite correct. I checked @DerNalia's page, and the html5 doctype is being used. HTML5 gives the [anchor element a transparent content model](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element), which allows it to contain block level elements. If it were the HTML4 spec, you'd be correct.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3722528/xhtml-placing-divs-in-a-tags : using HTML5 (which he is), you can put a `<div>`, inside an `<a>`. However, he also had to get rid of `inline-block` to make it work.

Answer (score 2):

```
.square_container {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

since vertical-align is baseline as default it tries to align the baseline of the text content in the boxes. since you dont have text in some of the boxes it positions them differently.

if you check the whole row you will se that they line upp again.

Answer (score 1):

Removing `inline-block` from all over the show fixes it.

Follow each of these steps:

- From `.player_take_square`, remove `position: absolute`.
- From `.ttt_square` and `.square_container`, remove `display: inline-block`.
- To `.ttt_square`, add `float: left`.
- To `.ttt_square`, add `overflow: auto` (to clear all the floated squares).

Works in Chrome and Firefox.

To make the X look presentable, I also tested these styles in Firefox:

```
.player_take_square {
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 140px;
    text-align: center
}
```

Comment: Tbh, you should really do these changes, as it would (probably) allow your game to work in IE just fine. `navigator.userAgent.indexOf('MSIE') ==-1`, which you have, is probably not needed.